# Pandas DataFrame nested dictionary (key+list(key:value))

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe:

```
Main    1      2     3

key1    ins    tbr    a
key1    inb    tba    b
key1    inr    tbe    c
```

I have this dataframe where 1,2,3 are columns and Main is set for index (set_index)
Is there a way to tell pandas on dictionary conversion that I need nested dictionary. I.e. that for each Key 1 row-wise theres a list of values, inside that list of values there's a dictionary in which columns (1,2,3)-> are keys as well. All this one by one, row by row.
Desired output:

```
key1:{1: 'ins', 2: 'tbr', 3: 'a'}
key1:{1: 'inb', 2: 'tba',3:'b'}
key1:{1: 'inr', 2: 'tbe', 3: 'c'}
key2:{....}
key2:{....}
etc
```

reproducible dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Main_keys", "1", "2","3"])   
df['1'] = ['ins','inb','inr']
df['2']= ['tbr','tba','tbe]
df['3']= ['a','b','c']


dataf.set_index('Main_keys', inplace = True)
```

no luck with this pseudo code approach.

- I tried with zip() as well doesn't seem to concatenate the list of dictionary to the column of the column with keys

```
import pandas as pd

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for elements_of_keys, list_of_dict in zip(col1, df_list):
    new_df[elements_of_keys] = list_of_dict
```

once I convert it to:

```
df = df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

I get really close to the answer however I don't know how to concetante or tell pandas that I need additonal column with bunch of keys (key1,key1,key1,key2,key2) -> with it's correspoding information

ultimately the desired output in json:

```
{​​​​​​​ "key1":[{​​​​​​​ "1": "ins", "2": "tbr", "3": "a", }​​​​​​​], {​​​​​​​ "key1":[{​​​​​​​ "1": "inb", "2": "tba", "3": "b", }​​​​​​​, { "key1":[{​​​​​​​ "1": "inr", "2": "tbe", "3": "c" }​​​​​​​] }​​​​​​​] }​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Comment: You're aware that you cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary, aren't you?

Comment: @QuangHoang Hoang thanks for your answer, of course, that's not what I'm asking. if you look at the code that I've just added once converting the dataframe to dictionary(orient='index') I get a list (in that list it's a dictionary) thus, it is possible to concatenate a list of dictionaries to iterated keys.

Comment: Do you mean `df.to_dict(orient='records')`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Hoang correct, my mistake. that's what I've used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually add the column:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({'Main':df.index, 'values': df.to_dict(orient='records')})
```

Output:

```
   Main                              values
0  key1  {'1': 'ins', '2': 'tbr', '3': 'a'}
1  key1  {'1': 'inb', '2': 'tba', '3': 'b'}
2  key1  {'1': 'inr', '2': 'tbe', '3': 'c'}
```

Or do you mean adding the keys as index:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.to_dict, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Main
key1    {'1': 'ins', '2': 'tbr', '3': 'a'}
key1    {'1': 'inb', '2': 'tba', '3': 'b'}
key1    {'1': 'inr', '2': 'tbe', '3': 'c'}
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions you've provided makes sense. however, ideally for the values it should be a list where 1,2,3 (initial columns) are keys as well.

Comment: Do you mean `{k:v.to_dict(orient='records') for k, v in df.groupby(level=0)}`?

Comment: format that I need to get ultimately in json is:
{​​​​​​​
  "key1":[{​​​​​​​
      "1": "ins",
      "2": "tbr",
      "3": "a",
    }​​​​​​​],
  {​​​​​​​
    "key1":[{​​​​​​​
      "1": "inb",
      "2": "tba",
      "3": "b",
    }​​​​​​​,
  {
    "key1":[{​​​​​​​
      "1": "inr",
      "2": "tbe",
      "3": "c"
    }​​​​​​​]
  }​​​​​​​]
}​​​​​​​

Comment: You should have specified that in your question :-)

Comment: I tried figuring it out from this point by myself, but since I can't make it happen you're right  @QuangHoang Hoang

Comment: I've edited the post and added the desired output in json. Seems like from given dataframe and suggested solutions it's not possible to get the desired output.  I don't get it in what logic/data type should I transform the dataframe, should the "Key1" 's  be KEYS while values data type is initially list?! in which theres again keys('1','2','3') and values ('ins','inb' etc etc) separately for each key1?! What would be the solution here. Thanks in advance! @QuangHoang Hoang

Comment: I guess I should re-post this question? Or if you have any idea let me know:)

Comment: @Ecko what you posted wasn't a valid JSON object. Try `list(df.apply(lambda x: {x.name:x.to_dict()}, axis=1))`

Comment: Thanks! @Quang Hoang

Answer (score 0):

df.set_index('Main', inplace=True)
df = df.to_dict(orient = 'records')

This answers the question, but not totally.

With this code, however, don't get why do all the 'key1' 's disappear shouldn't it be just instead of the indices, still is a mistery.

again apologies for not giving the json output which probably describes it the problem better

output should be like this in json:

{​​​​​​​ "key1":[{​​​​​​​ "1": "ins", "2": "tbr", "3": "a", }​​​​​​​],
{​​​​​​​ "key1":[{​​​​​​​ "1": "inb", "2": "tba", "3": "b", }​​​​​​​], { "key1":[{​​​​​​​ "1": "inr", "2": "tbe", "3": "c" }​​​​​​​] }​​​​​​​] }